# Need help with Watch Tag Issue

Tags: support, tags

I was in a post, I put my mouse over an item to click, I clicked and at the same instant a Watch Tag popped up and I clicked it instead. How do I clear Watch Tags - that is, how do I reset them?

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your watch tags in the side bar of the main site where there is an "edit" button on your watched tags.

[image]

Clicking "edit" will change the tags to add an "x" to remove them or add a box where you can add more tags:

[image]